# Find intersection position between SVG line and div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have this thing - http://jsbin.com/rehuzasila/edit?css,output, where I have 4 dots representing the intersection between gray line and the colored lines.

```
var $overlay = $('.overlay'),
    $handle = $('.handle'),
    width = $('.pane').width();


// ---------------------------


$handle.draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function(event, ui) {

        $overlay.width(width - ui.position.left);

    }

});
```

My problem is that when I drag the gray line I want to change the dots position to be always where the gray line intersect with the colored line.

[image]

Does anybody can explain me how to achive that?

Comment: You need to know the Y-values of those lines, given the X value, which would be the position of the grey line. To figure out the Y-values you need to know the function / equation that draws each line, so that you can plug in the X-value and get the Y-value as a result.

Comment: really usefull, but what do you mean 'function / equation that draws each line', I draw the lines in illustrator

Comment: Well that is a bit more problematic then... You obviously have some kind of graph here, but why are the lines drawn in illustrator then? Do they represent some actual data?

Comment: not really, thats what my client give to me. the thing I want is to find the Y position on a giving X position

Comment: Well since the svg lines are defined as paths and only contain a handful of coordinate points of the paths, you would have to do some kind of interpolation to find out the rest I guess. This would be very annoying and not too easy. To even check line-line intersection, you would need the start and end points of both lines, but since the svg lines are paths, it will not be so straight forward.